# LuaLatex: Clash between \color and \pagecolor since recent update. The \color definition only affects the first page of the document

Tags: color, luatex, miktex-update, pagecolor

Until updating MikTex today, I compiled a document with LuaLatex with a text color and page color defined through the xcolor package.
Since the update (I don't know what was updated exactly), the declaration \color{somecolor} only affects the first page of the document when a \pagecolor{anothercolor} is used.

A minimal example:

```
\documentclass{book}        
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\color{green}
\pagecolor{darkgray}
\begin{document}
    First page text.
    \newpage
    Second page text.%this appears black with Lua
\end{document}
```

This code, compiled with LuaLatex gives one page with green text and another page with black text.
This was not the behavior before updating, in that case the whole document had green text.
Compiled with PdfLatex it produces the pre-update behavior.
Commenting out \pagecolor{darkgray} also makes the whole document green again.

I would like to continue using LuaLatex because I need it to make plots (with pgfplots).
And I would like to change the text and page color globally in the preamble because I like to work with a dark page and light text.

Is there a way to fix this current behavior?
Or is there a better/different way to control the text and page color when compiling with LuaLatex?

Comment: I get green on black on both pages with an up to date texlve 2021, can you show the log you get for the test file?

Comment: It should be okay again soon, the fix has already been sent to ctan. As a workaround get the luatex.def from  here https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/graphics-def. miktex is sometimes a bit behind with updates.

Comment: Not sure if I get your point: You don't need LuaTeX for using pgfplots.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you for your feedback, it is solved now thanks to the update.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I don't need LuaTex for pgfplots in general, but I do need it to produce plots that have higher memory requirements (at least that's what I understood). I could produce basic plots with pdftex, but when I tried to plot with more data points it crashed; I overcame this using LuaTex.
Thank you all, problem solved (very quickly)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it is indeed good now after today's update, thank you for the quick fix.